# char pointer in struct and fprintf

Tags: c

In the function `imprimir` I have a problem when I do the fprintf in a file, because `_materias->nombres` does not return the value, for this reason, the text not show this information, please help because i don't know what is happening, if other person know how to create the in the struct nombre in array is better, because i don't do this for reason of the strtok because he return a char pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *nombre;
    int creditos;
    float nota;
} curso;

int conteo (FILE * _entrada);
void semestre (FILE * _entrada, curso * _materias, int *_cantidad,
            int *_ganadas, int *_perdidas, float *_promedio);
void imprimir (curso * _materias, int *_cantidad, int *_ganadas,
            int *_perdidas, float *_promedio);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ganadas = 0;
    int perdidas = 0;
    float promedio = 0.0;
    int cantidad = 0;
    char archivoEntrada[256];
    curso *materias;
    printf ("Archivo de entrada \n");
    scanf ("%255s", archivoEntrada);
    FILE *entrada;
    entrada = fopen (archivoEntrada, "r");

    if (entrada == NULL) {
        printf ("No se logro abrir el archivo de entrada\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cantidad = conteo (entrada);

    materias = (curso *) malloc (sizeof (curso) * cantidad);

    semestre (entrada, materias, &cantidad, &ganadas, &perdidas, &promedio);

    imprimir (materias, &cantidad, &ganadas, &perdidas, &promedio);

    free (materias);
}

int conteo (FILE * _entrada)
{
    int i = 0;
    char auxiliar[40];

    while (!feof (_entrada)) {
        fgets (auxiliar, 40, _entrada);
        i++;
    }

    rewind (_entrada);
    return i / 3;
}

void semestre (FILE * _entrada, curso * _materias, int *_cantidad,
            int *_ganadas, int *_perdidas, float *_promedio)
{
    int i = 0;
    int sumaCreditos = 0;
    float sumaNotas = 0.0;
    char auxiliar2[100];
    char *token;

    fgets (auxiliar2, 100, _entrada);

    while (i < *_cantidad) {
        fgets (auxiliar2, 100, _entrada);
        token = strtok (auxiliar2, ":");
        token = strtok (NULL, ":");
        (_materias->nombre) = token;

        fgets (auxiliar2, 100, _entrada);
        token = strtok (auxiliar2, ":");
        float val2 = atof (strtok (NULL, ":"));
        (_materias->nota) = val2;

        fgets (auxiliar2, 100, _entrada);
        token = strtok (auxiliar2, ":");
        float val = atoi (strtok (NULL, ":"));
        (_materias->creditos) = val;
        sumaCreditos = sumaCreditos + (_materias->creditos);

        if ((_materias->nota) < 3.0) {
            *_perdidas = (*_perdidas) + 1;
        }
        else {
            *_ganadas = (*_ganadas) + 1;
        }

        sumaNotas = sumaNotas + ((_materias->nota) * (_materias->creditos));
        i++;
        *_materias++;
    }

    *_promedio = (sumaNotas / sumaCreditos);
}

void imprimir (curso * _materias, int *_cantidad, int *_ganadas,
            int *_perdidas, float *_promedio)
{
    char archivoSalida[256];
    FILE *salida;
    printf ("Archivo de salida \n");
    scanf ("%255s", archivoSalida);
    salida = fopen (archivoSalida, "w");

    if (salida == NULL) {
        printf ("No se logro abrir el archivo de salida\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int i = 0;
    fprintf (salida, "Archivo de Salida: \n");
    fprintf (salida, "Materia\tNota\tCreditos \n");

    while (i < *_cantidad) {
        fprintf (salida, "%s\t%f\t%d \n", (_materias->nombre),
                (_materias->nota), (_materias->creditos));
        *_materias++;
        i++;
    }

    fprintf (salida, "\nTotal de materias: %d \n", *_cantidad);
    fprintf (salida, "Materias ganadas: %d \n", *_ganadas);
    fprintf (salida, "Materias perdidas: %d \n", *_perdidas);
    fprintf (salida, "Promedio ponderado: %f \n", *_promedio);
}
```

Comment: Maybe because `token` is a stack variable.

Comment: Please indent your code properly because it is hard to read that way, also please put space character after "}" and space after "," and space before and after "=" equals.  I answer lots of questions. I even wrote a program for someone today to teach them because I asked them to indent the code and they did. It's just respect. People here have a hard enough time without having to try to read carelessly posted code. Be considered and help the people who are trying to help you.

Comment: This is unreadable. Plase clean up the mess.

Comment: ok, thanks, now the problem is, the value nombre is a char pointer, equal at the value given from strtok, in the function imprimir i do "fprintf(salida,"%s\t%f\t%d \n",(_materias->nombre),(_materias->nota),(_materias->creditos));" and this not function for nombre

Comment: It appears your use of `*_materias++;` is wrong in both functions. It looks like you mean to increment `_materias->creditos++`. (or some other value that makes sense to increment)

Comment: You want to replace `(_materias->nombre) = token;` by `(_materias->nombre) = strdup(token);`